# Is there a Firefox App equivalent of the JupyterLab Chrome App?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have recently begun working with Jupyterlab and went and set it up to be a desktop Chrome app via this command on the config file:

```
c.LabApp.browser = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito --app=%s'
```

However, I do not regularly use Chrome and would rather the app open as a firefox.exe. That way, I do not have to have Chrome on my computer just for this one app. I just do not have the knowledge on how to do this. All the tutorials I see are focused on doing this on a Chrome app, so I am lost on even if this can be done as a "Firefox App".

Comment: Firefox does not have an "Apps" feature.

Comment: That's a shame. Is there a particular reason as to why not? I do not like the tracking that comes with using Chrome.